# pushviewcontroller crashes on distribution build but not debug

Tags: debugging, uitableview, ios6, pushviewcontroller

I have encountered a strange situation where one of my apps has stopped working in iOS6.  The actual code is simple and is  ARC enabled.  I have a table with a navigation controller and when a row in the table is tapped it pushes a view controller.   The code works fine in the simulator and in debug build when I switch to distribution build the code crashes after pushing the view controller.

I set some nslog outputs and can see that it gets as far as view will appear before crashing.

I've tried setting the distribution build with compiler optimization -Oo without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

i've resolved this. somehow ARC was disabled on the distribution build setting.